# preparing job for table clean up in oracle not to have entries more than 5 days old

Tags: oracle

I have the below schedule job in dbms scheduler which is working perfectly below is the job

```
begin
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
         job_name             => 'KEEP_STATS_DBNEW5',
         job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
         job_action           => 'begin
  insert into my_log_table3 (MDATE, MUSER, MCNT)
  select sysdate, osuser, count(osuser)
  from v$session
  group by osuser;
  commit;
end;',
         start_date           => timestamp '2016-11-08 18:30:00',
         repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=10;',
         enabled              => TRUE);
end;
/
```

so basically this job inserts some data in table named my_log_table3  in which there is also once columned named date also now my query is i have to also clean this table let  say i want only the entries of last 5 days only rest all the rows should be deleted

So please advise is I want to write a separate job which name would be  `my_log_table3_cleanup` and what should the oracle statement inside this job

also please advise if  I get delete statement to achieve the same then I can also configure my job to run at least once in night at around 23:00 hrs to achieve the same

Comment: You can create a job and simply use a delete statement in it; where is the issue? are you having problems in finding rows older than 5 days?

Comment: @Aleksej yes please request you to please show so that i can grsp more Thanks in advance

Comment: To delete the rows older than 5 days, you may need something like `delete my_log_table3 where mdate <= sysdate -5`. Using it in a job is straightforward

Comment: @Aleksej request you to please advise whyi can not add it in dbms scheduler job itself

Comment: I can't understand the issue; are you having an error? if so, please edit the question posting what you tried and the error you are having

Comment: @Aleksej done please check

Comment: done what? I don't see any code or error. If you have some code and an error, please post them. If you simply want to know how to use dbms_scheduler, you'll find many examples with a simple google search; for example [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_linux_oracle_dbms_scheduler_create_job.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
begin
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
         job_name             => 'KEEP_STATS_DBNEW5',
         job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
         job_action           => 'begin
  insert into my_log_table3 (MDATE, MUSER, MCNT)
  select sysdate, osuser, count(osuser)
  from v$session
  group by osuser;
  if to_char(sysdate, ''HH24MI'') = 2300 then
     delete from my_log_table3 where MDATE <= sysdate -5;
  end if;
  commit;
end;',
         start_date           => timestamp '2016-11-08 18:30:00',
         repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=10;',
         enabled              => TRUE);
end;
/
```

However, this would be really ugly coding. Better create a separate job with `repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;BYHOUR=23;BYMINUTE=00'` which deletes old data.